# How to upgrade MFC project from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010(or above)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I am working on upgrading a legacy C++ MFC app from Visual Studio 2008 to 2010 and above. It is a huge project. I know that I can run the project in any version of visual studio by keeping the Platform Toolset the same(v90 instead of v100+) but I do not want to use that toolset. The project builds fine but throws exceptions on running(these exceptions were not thrown in VS2008).

What are some good ways of approaching this problem? Any help is highly appreciated.

Edit:I did open it in VS2017 and 2019 and it did bulid properly. The only difference is new exceptions are being thrown when running the application using the VS2017 platform toolset. These exceptions are not thrown when using the VS2008 platform toolset(v90) in VS2017. I do not want to keep VS2008 installed on my computer to keep using that toolset. I guess my question is - what is the best way to figure out what all has changed in the two platform toolsets and how do I go about making the required changes to my code? Is there a way to avoid making all the changes?

Comment: I simply kept a backup and opens the project in the latest Visual studio. It performed some migration by iyself and then I tryied to compile it. I dealt with the issues it raised, obtaining new third party libraries where they were needed by the package.

Comment: Why not just go straight to Visual Studio 2019?  Using a decades old compiler is not worth it, especially one that is not C++ 11 compliant.  Second, maybe the VS 2008 version had hidden bugs, but the newer compiler exposed them?  Third, the absolute minimum compiler to go to, IMO, is VS 2015 with update 3.  Anything below that is just not worth doing an upgrade to.

Comment: In theory, you could just open your old project in the new IDE and build it. I suggest you could refer to the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/upgrading-projects-from-earlier-versions-of-visual-cpp?view=vs-2019).

Comment: *"What are some good ways of approaching this problem?"* - What's the problem?

Comment: I did open it in VS2017 and 2019 and it did _bulid_ properly. The only difference is new exceptions are being thrown when running the application using the VS2017 platform toolset. These exceptions are not thrown when using the VS2008 platform toolset(v90) in VS2017. I do not want to keep VS2008 installed on my computer to keep using that toolset.

I guess my question is - what is the best way to figure out what all has changed in the two platform toolsets and how do I go about making the required changes to my code? Is there a way to avoid making all the changes?

Comment: @kidcudi2765 `new exceptions are being thrown` No one can guess what those are or why, without seeing some code and context.

Comment: It's not at all helpful to figure out *"what all has changed"*. That would just expose you to too much information you would then need to filter. Instead, focus on solving your immediate issue: Set up your debugger to break on uncaught exceptions, and start investigating from there. The callstack is helpful in reconstructing context. It's almost guaranteed that there is a bug in your code, that only started surfacing after the upgrade. It's not that the upgrade broke your code. It was broken all along, most likely. Without any information there's little more we can do to help, though.

Comment: `_AFXCMN_INLINE void CToolTipCtrl::RelayEvent(_In_ LPMSG lpMsg)
 { ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd));  ::SendMessage(m_hWnd, TTM_RELAYEVENT, 0, (LPARAM)lpMsg); }`

That Assert is what is breaking my application. (from afxcmn.inl)
The windows in my app are not populating properly - they are null. 
Whenever I take my pointer on to that window - this assert throws an exception.

Apologies - I am really new to this and MFC programming.

Comment: Your debugger shows a callstack, that eventually goes back to your code. That's where you should start investigating. Presumably, you are trying to access windows too early, before they have been created. There are countless ways to do that. We cannot help you without a [mcve].